# Oracle PLSQL Print Bulk Batch Output After Each Batch Completion

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bulkupdate

I have below plsql bulk script which print the output with each batch size and batch completion time, after the entire update is completed.

```
set timing on echo on verify on feedback on
set serveroutput on
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback

declare 
    type update_id is table of tbl_source%rowtype;
    tab      update_id := update_id();
    start_time   number;
    end_time     number;
    c_limit      int;  -- bulk collect limit
    cursor load_cur is
    select * from tbl_source;

begin
    open load_cur;
    start_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
    loop
        fetch load_cur
             bulk collect into tab limit &c_limit;
        begin
            forall i in tab.first..tab.last
                
                update tbl_target
                   set value = tab(i).name
                 where id = tab(i).id
                ;

                dbms_output.put_line('Bulk    (' || tab.count || ' rows): ' || (dbms_utility.get_time - start_time)/100 || 'seconds');

            exception
            when others then
                dbms_output.put_line('Updated '|| sql%rowcount                                     || ' rows.');
                dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
            commit;

        end;

        exit when load_cur%notfound;
    end loop;

    end_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
    dbms_output.put_line('Bulk Update Time taken: ' || (end_time - start_time)/100 || 'seconds');
    close load_cur;
end;
```

```
Bulk    (50000 rows): 112.87seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 186.74seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 255.5seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 326.01seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 428.44seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 503.91seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 570.92seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 636.56seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 686.8seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 748.89seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 811.76seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 865.96seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 915.68seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 964.28seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 1018.27seconds
Bulk    (50000 rows): 1098.99seconds
Bulk    (8359 rows): 1110.22seconds
Bulk Update Time taken: 1110.22seconds


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:18:30.822
```

But I need the batch size and completion time to be printed as soon as the 1st batch is completed and so on for the next batches. So I would know how many batches got completed and how many are pending.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't how `dbms_output` works.